# Opening Multiple HTML Files (Reports) from a Given Folder

Tags: excel, vba

The following code opens up a menu to select a folder from which to draw a desired html file.  Currently, this only picks the first file in the folder selected and no others.  However, I would like to modify this to select ALL html files in a given folder and open each in a separate workbook.  Is there an easy way to modify this code to do this?  I should note that the code does seem to give me an error even now when it opens the first file, which I suspect has something to do with it being HTML while excel's import methods support XML.  Any help would be appreciated!

```
Sub ImportXMLData()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim strFolder As String, strFile As String
Dim xlWkBk As Workbook, xmlFile As Workbook, LastRow As Long
strFolder = GetFolder
If strFolder = "" Then Exit Sub
strFile = Dir(strFolder & "\*.html", vbNormal)
Set xlWkBk = ThisWorkbook
While strFile <> ""
  LastRow = xlWkBk.Sheets(1).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row + 1
  Set xmlFile = Workbooks.OpenXML(Filename:=strFolder & "\" & strFile)
  xmlFile.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Copy
  xlWkBk.Sheets(1).Cells(LastRow, 1).Paste
  xmlFile.Close SaveChanges:=False
  strFile = Dir()
Wend
Set xmlFile = Nothing: Set xlWkBk = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Function GetFolder() As String
Dim oFolder As Object
GetFolder = ""
Set oFolder = CreateObject("Shell.Application").BrowseForFolder(0, "Choose a folder", 0)
If (Not oFolder Is Nothing) Then GetFolder = oFolder.Items.Item.Path
Set oFolder = Nothing
End Function
```

My apologies for the lengthy code, but some sample of the rearrangement sub would look like this:

```
Sub Rearranging()
'
' Rearranging Macro
'

'
    Range("A1:J2").Select
    Range("A2").Activate
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("A1:J1").Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = True
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = True
    End With
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = True
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = True
    End With
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = True
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = True
    End With
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = True
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = True
    End With
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = True
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = True
    End With
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = True
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = True
    End With
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = True
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = True
    End With
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = True
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = True
    End With
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = True
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = True
    End With
    Selection.UnMerge
    Range("A3").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("A2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("A3").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "date"
    Range("A7:B10").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("B1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True
    Range("A13:B14").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Range("F1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True
    Range("A22:B27").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Range("H1").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "amount approved"
    Range("I1").Select
    Range("A22:B27").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("J1").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ""
    Range("J1").Select
    Range("A22:B27").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("J1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True
    Range("A20").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Range("H2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Columns("I:I").ColumnWidth = 16.14
    Range("P1").Select
    Range("A31:B31").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Range("P1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True
    Range("A37:B37").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-21
    Range("Q1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=18
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=21
    Range("A45:B62").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-45
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 2
    Range("R1").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-6
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=63
    Range("A74:C77").Select
    Range("C77").Activate
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-3
    Range("A68:E82").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Range("AJ1").Select
    Range("A68:E68").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Range("AJ1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("AJ2:AN5").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("AJ1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "[Index Date Member# Member Name]"
    Range("AK1:AN1").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("AJ2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ""
    Range("D69:D82").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("A86:B87").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("AK1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True
    Range("A95:G100").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 17
    Range("AL2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True
End Sub
```

I have removed quite a few With statements to cut down on space.  I will test out your code in its current form now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code opens the each file in the separate workbook and saves the files in the same folder

**Tested**

```
Sub ImportXMLData()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Dim strFolder As String, strFile As String
Dim xlWkBk As Workbook, xmlFile As Workbook, LastRow As Long
strFolder = GetFolder
If strFolder = "" Then Exit Sub
strFile = Dir(strFolder & "\*.html", vbNormal)
Set xlWkBk = ThisWorkbook
While strFile <> ""
  LastRow = xlWkBk.Sheets(1).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row + 1
  Set xmlFile = Workbooks.OpenXML(Filename:=strFolder & "\" & strFile)
  xmlFile.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Copy
 Workbooks.Add
 ActiveSheet.Paste

call Rearranging ' This will calls sub for each file

  ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs strFolder & "\" & Replace(xmlFile.Name, ".html", ""), xlNormal
  xmlFile.Close SaveChanges:=False
  ActiveWorkbook.Close
  strFile = Dir()
Wend
Set xmlFile = Nothing: Set xlWkBk = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub

Function GetFolder() As String
Dim oFolder As Object
GetFolder = ""
Set oFolder = CreateObject("Shell.Application").BrowseForFolder(0, "Choose a folder", 0)
If (Not oFolder Is Nothing) Then GetFolder = oFolder.Items.Item.Path
Set oFolder = Nothing
End Function
```

*Let me know if you need any help*

Comment: Thanks so much for your help!  I am looking to have each file open in the same worksheet and workbook, however.  Thinking about this more carefully I may not need that to be the case actually.  I will record a macro performing some of the rearrangement steps I am looking to perform on each file.  Would it be possible to adjust the code to perform the rearrangements upon opening a given file and then, for each file this is done to, stack the results of this in a new workbook?  Perhaps this will be more clear once I have the rearrangement steps.

Comment: I hope above code works perfectly. . Rearrangement are possible but u need to explain me more .

Comment: Check the updated code. To avoid alerts. you need to add the below code Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Comment: Your code is great! It now cycles as desired.  The above questions are all I need to fine tune things.  I really appreciate your help.  I did take a look at that and managed to get the compatibility check to stop.  Do you happen to also know how to implement ThisWorkbook.CheckCompatibility = False.  I came across it as a solution too but I don't think I can just add it to the top of the macro.

Comment: Will do, would you happen to know how to address implementing the rearrangements? Given that all the Excel files are together in one folder I am essentially asking how to create a loop for that bulk of With statements above (I will be adding more With statements in the full macro, including a step that creates a list and sub-list structure to fit a table in one cell, as I describe in this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22356132/parsing-sub-lists-in-excel

Comment: If you want to call the rearranging sub for each file ..Check the updated code .

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49582/discussion-between-sathish-k-and-stopwatch)